# Is Parallelization of NetTrain possible?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I was planning to build a Neural Network model and create a list of the same model with the elements of the list being different Initializations of the same model.
Is it possible to Train the entire list consisting of say 5 Neural Network models, simultaneously, either by using parallelization technique, or by mapping the NetTrain function on the list?
Any help will be highly appreciated, as this will save a lot of time for my project.

Comment: I don't believe it makes a lot of sense, because `NetTrain` automatically uses all available cores on the current machine (if using TargetDevice->CPU) anyways. Because of this the time difference would be negligible just training them serially anyways. (If you have the option of a bunch of different kernels running on different machines or something, disregard this message)

Comment: Are you asking if WL has anything similar to [TensorFlow distributed training](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training)?